# .net localization for non-strings

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

I am localizing a WPF application using .resx files. I created copies of main Resources files like Resources.en-US.resx or Resources.cs-CZ.resx. Works well for strings. However, I can't figure out how to localize other files like images or documents in resource files.

When I add a new image to Resources file (either Resources.en-US.resx or Resources.cs-CZ.resx), a copy of the file is always copied to /Resources directory. So there cannot be multiple versions of one file for multiple languages, because in one directory there can be only one file with same name.

Ideal solution would be if images from localized resources would be copied in subdirectories like /Resources/en-Us. In current conditions, I am unable to localize images and documents using .resx files. Any ideas how I can achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following MSDN post [Resources and Localization in ASP.NET 2.0 - Displaying Localized Images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163566.aspx#S6) states:

> While ASP.NET 2.0 doesn't directly support localizing image files, it doesn't require too much custom code to achieve the desired effect.

And provides the following work around:

> You can start by adding the localized versions of an image file to localized versions of a global resource file. For example, the English version of LitwareSlogan.png has been added to the global resource file named Litware.resx while the French version of LitwareSlogan.fr.png has been added to Litware.fr.resx. The resources in both resource files have been given the same name of LitwareSlogan.

Complete sample code is provided at the site.